# Google Maps, some devices returning different SHA1 Keys

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

In testing the debug release of an App (testing through Fabric) a couple of users were experiencing a blank Google Map (95% of users weren't).  I couldn't reproduce it on the emulator or on any of the 6 Android devices I own.  Eventually I managed to reproduce it on the AWS Device Farm on an LG Optimus L70, and reading through the logs it turns out that the SHA1 key is different.  Here is the dump I get from the CERT.RSA file (with sensitive data XX out):

```
build\outputs\apk>keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 160d8c0

Valid from: Wed Sep 17 20:41:47 PDT 2014 until: Fri Sep 09 20:41:47 PDT 2044
    Certificate fingerprints:
             MD5:  82:17:27:A9:4B:63:AD:F8:54:AC:94:C2:EB:XX:XX:XX
             SHA1: 66:76:69:7D:83:4F:8F:8D:01:F6:F9:12:AF:35:16:78:XX:XX:XX:XX
             SHA256: 91:EF:E0:0E:23:54:6D:C6:48:B8:BA:B4:E2:75:82:D0:A7:9A:49:D9:E5:D2:DA:E8:35:62:37:27:XX:XX:XX:XX
             Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
             Version: 3
```

And the SHA1 (66:76:69:7D:83:4F:8F:8D:01:F6:F9:12:AF:35:16:78:XX:XX:XX:XX) from this works perfectly in Developers Console with all my local devices, however, in the logs from LG Optimus L70, I get a totally different SHA1 reported:

```
Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyA5kvTz4UL*********************
Android Application (;): 8D:2E:22:6C:30:4C:DD:85:05:5D:10:67:08:88:75:8A:XX:XX:XX:XX;com.sample.app
```

This is the same APK, just on different devices.  Is there some way that some devices are getting different SHA1's?  I hope this won't be an issue with a signed release APK, but I am currently testing with the Debug APK's and don't want to switch testing to Release unless I have to. Also I am just confused about what is going on, and how this could happen?  Is there any reason I have to worry about the signed release version having this problem?

Comment: From the AWS Device Farm FAQ: _"On Android, we resign the app. This may break functionality that depends on the app signature, such as the Google Maps Android API. "_

Comment: @Michael - Well, that would explain it.   Still a mystery as to why some devices would fail though.